# what is the meaning of current request parameter in rails?isn`t it params[:xxxx]？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I write this:

```
book_structure_path(structure)
```

I get an error:

```
book_structure_url failed to generate from {:controller=>"structures", :book_id=>#Structure id: 1, book_id: 1, unit: 1, chapter: 1, title: .........
```

but this:

```
book_structure_path(params[:book_id], structure)
```

is okay.

There is only an id in `params` and I just need the id but Rails filled the object in it?

Comment: The title seems misleading - this is really a question about a URL generation error.

Comment: I read that if the parameter is missing rails will fill it with  current request parameter,am I wrong?   It did filled,although not right...= =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails url helpers doesn't read then params[] hash.

They take explicit params and build url from them. You need to pass every data, in this case book and a structure

```
book_structure_url(book, structure)
```

or

```
book_structure_url(params[:id], params[:structure_id])
```

or whatever you have to identify the route.

Comment: Any article about what rails will do when parameter is missing?

Comment: I don't know any. But the *_path methods behave like the nesting itself. If the nesting is books -> structure -> chapter the expected order of the params is book, structure, chapter. 
If any param is missing it will try build the route with nil.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your error:

```
book_structure_url failed to generate from {:controller=>"structures", :book_id=>#Structure id: 1, book_id: 1, unit: 1, chapter: 1, title: .........
```

It is trying to use the Structure as the Book record - this is clearly wrong. The Structure is a nested resource, it relies on a Book resource as its parent. You'll need to pass it to the path helper as well:

```
book_structure_url(book, structure)
```

Comment: That is the things I already know.Please focus on my question,won`t rails fill up the parameters that i missed?with current params[]?

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass in the id instead:

`book_structure_path(structure.id)`

It does seem like it should have figured this out though, but this is a workaround. Maybe there's something else in your code that is causing this.

Something weird in your `routes.rb` file? Maybe your route for `structures` is not the typical `/:controller/:id/:action` kind?

Comment: this is a nesting route,code like this :
map.resources :books do |book|
    book.resources :structures
  end